# Error: cannot open display: localhost:0.0 - trying to open Firefox from CentOS 6.2 64bit and display on Win7

Tags: x11, x11-forwarding

I am on a Windows7 machine and I'm trying to get firefox to open on the centOS machine, but be displayed on my current screen. 
When typing `firefox` in terminal, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: cannot open display: localhost:0.0
```

To setup the display I used the command

```
$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

Some site suggested using the following, but it didn't work either:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

I am using PuTTY and I have the `Enable X11 forwarding` check box checked and XMing is running on Windows. Additionally, the sshd_config on centOS file seems to be setup properly as well:

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep -i x11
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

I've looked over numerous pages and searched StackOverflow as well, but none have managed to help me in any way. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question might be more suitable at http://superuser.com/. Besides, in Xming there is `XLaunch` utility, which allows to connect to remote server and launch an application without explicitly using PuTTY and such. Have you tried it? Does it works?

Comment: try it without setting the DISPLAY variable... you shouldn't actually need that

Comment: @aland I've looked on the Internet to see what the XLaunch Utility is, I don't know what you mean when you say I should try to launch the application without PuTTY. I just noticed that `XMing` has a `Command Processor`, but I don't know how to use it. - Also, I'm not too sure how to migrate my question.

Comment: @scott654 When I try that, I get the following: `Error: no display specified`. All the suggestions on the Internet say that I should set the display variable to fix that error, but that doesn't do anything for me :(

Comment: @Dana XLaunch is part of XMing distribution, it is a GUI for configuring XMing. By the way, you should not specify DISPLAY variable manually, PuTTY should do that for you. Most likely for remote server you X is not :0.0, but something else (usually :10.0); although your XMing is considering itself to be :0.0, PuTTY does port-forwarding magic to hide that, since :0.0 might be alredy taken by other user or default X or smth. else, so it autimatically finds some available X display number and uses it.

Comment: @Dana Only moderators can migrate questions, you should just flag your question as belonging to SU

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, it turns out that X11 wasn't actually installed on the centOS. There didn't seem to be any indication anywhere of it not being installed. I did the following command and now firefox opens:

```
yum groupinstall 'X Window System'
```

Hope this answer will help others that are confused :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem too. I have been searching all over the net to find this solution. Now I only need gvim to find the fonts and I'm ready to go...

Comment: ... and that was solved by installing the X11 fonts. (in Fedora: `yum search fonts` to get a list of fonts, and then install relevant X11 fonts)

Comment: I have the same problem but I dont have ROOT right. Any solution in such case ?

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue once and was able to resolve it by fixing of my /etc/hosts. It just was unable to resolve localhost name... Details are here: http://itvictories.com/node/6

In fact, there is 99% that error related to /etc/hosts file

X server just unable to resolve localhost and all consequent actions just fails.

Please be sure that you have a record like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

in your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Can you post the answer here instead of a link pointing to it?

Comment: The link does not load for me =/. I receive an internal server error. Could you post your answer here, please?

Comment: The link is broken. I have 127.0.0.1 localhost in my /etc/hosts still not working.

Comment: In my case also, I have 127.0.0.1 localhost in my /etc/hosts still not working.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error message:

```
Error: Can't open display: localhost:13.0
```

This fixed it for me:

```
export DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"
```

You can use this too:

```
export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:10.0"
```

Comment: >xauth list   This will print the authorization entries for all the displays. Check what number to use.

Comment: export DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"

this worked for me. Thank you so much.
Centos 8 accessing via MobaXTerm v21.2
X11 tab with Dwm <--- i think.

Answer (score 1):

before start make sure of installation:

```
yum install -y xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-xauth xorg-x11-apps
```

1. start `xming` or `cygwin`
2. make connection with X11 forwarding (in putty don't forget to set localhost:0.0 for X display location)
3. edit sshd.cong and restart

```
     cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X
                             X11Forwarding yes
                             X11DisplayOffset 10
AddressFamily inet
```

4. Without the X11 forwarding, you are subjected to the X11 SECURITY and then you must:
   authorize the remote server to make a connection with the local X Server using a method (for instance, the xhost command)
   set the display environment variable to redirect the output to the X server of your local computer.
   In this example:
   192.168.2.223 is the IP of the server
   192.168.2.2 is the IP of the local computer where the x server is installed. localhost can also be used.

```
blablaco@blablaco01 ~
$ xhost 192.168.2.223
192.168.2.223 being added to access control list

blablaco@blablaco01 ~
$ ssh -l root 192.168.2.223
root@192.168.2.223s password:
Last login: Sat May 22 18:59:04 2010 from etcetc
[root@oel5u5 ~]# export DISPLAY=192.168.2.2:0.0
[root@oel5u5 ~]# echo $DISPLAY
192.168.2.2:0.0
[root@oel5u5 ~]# xclock&
```

Then the xclock application must launch.

Check it on putty or mobaxterm and don't check in remote desktop Manager software.
Be careful for user that sudo in.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused due to mismatch in .Xauthority file. Which initially showed up with "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1" error and then "Error: cannot open display: :0.0" afterwards

Regenerating the .Xauthorityfile from the user under which I am running the vncserver and resetting the password with a restart of the vnc service and dbus service fixed the issue for me.